# Easier way to find substrings within strings (Obj C)

Tags: objective-c, string, substring

I'm just wondering if there is a simpler way to find a substring within a string in Objective C.

My string is question is this: (messy I know...)

```
filename.cpp - line: 1 "comment 1"\nfilename.cpp - line: 1 "comment 2"\nfilename.cpp - line: 1 "comment 3"\n
```

So what I want to do is extract into an array all the bits between the quotation marks. I've been messing around with the **componentsSeparatedByString** method to try to manipulate the string enough to leave me with the "comments" but it just seems a very messy way to do it.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Use NSRegularExpression.

Comment: Use `NSScanner` to parse the string or use `rangeOfString` to find the index of the quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use NSScanner to scan for `\"` and store every other substring in an array

```
NSString *string = @"filename.cpp - line: 1 \"comment 1\"\nfilename.cpp - line: 1 \"comment 2\"\nfilename.cpp - line: 1 \"comment 3\"\n";
NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:string];
NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray array];

while (YES) {
    NSString *s;
    [scanner scanUpToString:@"\"" intoString:NULL];
    [scanner setScanLocation:[scanner scanLocation]+1];
    [scanner scanUpToString:@"\"" intoString:&s];
    if(s)
        [array addObject:s];
    if(![scanner isAtEnd])
        [scanner setScanLocation:[scanner scanLocation]+1];
    else break;
}
```

result:

```
array = (
    comment 1,
    comment 2,
    comment 3
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I don't understand your question precisely, but:
If your strings to be parsed always start with something not to be included, i.e. if the 1st substring to be extracted is not at the beginning of your string, you could use

```
NSMutableArray *components = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray: [yourString componentsSeparatedByString:@"\""]];
for (int i=0; i<components.count; i++) {
   [components removeObjectAtIndex:i];
}
```